# How can I get the colorize effect back to GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I used to choose the "colorize" option and automatically the image would tirn blue/greenish.

When I last updated GIMP to its latest version, the colorize button no longer works. The same is happening for the HUE options. On the toolbox appears the message:

> This tool has no options

Is there another way to get the colorizing effect to an image?

Comment: Which version / platform? I'm using v2.8.6 (I believe the latest version) on Windows and both Colorize and Hue-Saturation options work OK for me. "colorize button" - which "button"? Both these options are available from the "Colors menu", I'm not aware of a button? There are no options for these tools, so "This tool has no options" in the tools window is correct. However, selecting either of these tools should open a popup window with the tool's controls. My guess is that this window is perhaps appearing off your screen and the "preview" option is unchecked?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the wrong place, "This tool has no options" on the toolbox is normal, it is always there, even when the tool is successfully opened. When the Colorize settings window does not open, you should look at the status bar at the bottom of the window. It is easy to miss since when you move the mouse over the menu, hints are flickering there, so you don't notice when it has changed to something important, and then the message disappears in 7 seconds. The error looks like this:

[image: Colorize operates only on RGB color layers.]

Here I was trying to run it on an opened GIF file. Since in GIF colors are stored in indexed format, I had to switch the mode from Indexed to RGB (Image - Mode - RGB) to be able to use the tool.

Comment: Can you make this a complete answer by saying how to switch to index mode?

Comment: @crashspringfield, it's in the answer: go the main menu item Image, then Mode.